# iPhone won't connect in Xcode 7.1 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I connect my iPhone (iOS 9.0.2), I get the error:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.
>   Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000076)

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 7.1 beta you should run run iOS 9.1 beta. **Using a GM iOS and a beta Xcode together leads to this kind of problems**.

Simply use Xcode 7.0 GM with your installed version of iOS.